# How to get output in django query

Tags: python, django

```
Table : Demo

ID  Name   Score
 1   A       10
 2   B        5
 3   B        2
 4   A       12
 5   A        5
```

I have created the above table with `data`. Now I need to get the **output** like below

```
Name Name_count Name_score
 A      3         27
 B      2         7
```

Anyone help me to do with `django` query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from django.db.models import Count, Sum
Members.objects.values('name').annotate(Name_count=Count('name'), Name_score=Sum('score'))
```